# Any automated process for recoloring or adding indicators to axis labels based on categories in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I have made some bar plots in ggplots and was hoping to indicate that each bar is part of larger category via the axis label. Like the plot below for example:

[image]

I understand that I could use aesthetics to recolor the axis labels manually, or mutate the dataframe to call specific colors. (See this post for an example: [ggplot color axis labels based on variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956199/ggplot-color-axis-labels-based-on-variable))

But is there no automated process in ggplots to do this and generate a legend, similar to fill/ scale_fill?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528915/assign-color-to-2-different-geoms-and-get-2-different-legends) shows how to use `ggnewscale` to add a second color legend, perhaps that will help.  Another option would be just to facet on the Island group, with `scales=free_x`.

Comment: This is a neat trick, tucking that away for later!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the `ggside` package for this. A simple tutorial can be found [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggside/vignettes/ggside_basic_usage.html).

#### Dummy input from the package `gapminder`:

Since I don't have your dataframe, I'll use the `gapminder` dataset as an example.

```r
library(gapminder)

test_df <- gapminder %>% 
  group_by(country) %>% 
  slice_head(n = 3) %>% 
  arrange(country) %>% 
  head(n = 10)

# A tibble: 10 × 6
# Groups:   country [4]
   country     continent  year lifeExp      pop gdpPercap
   <fct>       <fct>     <int>   <dbl>    <int>     <dbl>
 1 Afghanistan Asia       1952    28.8  8425333      779.
 2 Afghanistan Asia       1957    30.3  9240934      821.
 3 Afghanistan Asia       1962    32.0 10267083      853.
 4 Albania     Europe     1952    55.2  1282697     1601.
 5 Albania     Europe     1957    59.3  1476505     1942.
 6 Albania     Europe     1962    64.8  1728137     2313.
 7 Algeria     Africa     1952    43.1  9279525     2449.
 8 Algeria     Africa     1957    45.7 10270856     3014.
 9 Algeria     Africa     1962    48.3 11000948     2551.
10 Angola      Africa     1952    30.0  4232095     3521.
```

#### ggplot

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggside)

ggplot(test_df, aes(country, lifeExp, fill = as.character(year))) + 
  geom_col() + 
  geom_xsidetile(aes(xfill = continent), position = "fill") + 
  scale_xsidey_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  ggside(x.pos = "bottom", draw_x_on = "main") + 
  theme_ggside_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is grea thanks so much! Is there a similar process if I wanted to recolor the axis labels themselves rather than have a bar? for instance Could I color "Afghanistan" green etc..?

Comment: I just want to put this post here for reference may help some folks who are having similar challenges.

Comment: @N.F.F. You can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64795448/16647496). The package to use is `ggtext`, which employs CSS syntax to color the axis texts.