# add extra annotation to geom_tile in ggplot2 using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, annotations, heatmap

I have the a data.frame, to generate a heatmap plot, I just want to add a line with extra annotations in the upper side of the plot using the category column

```
head(dfx)
           gene     sample value category
1 BJE04_RS21740 SAMPLE-300     1     cat1
2 BJE04_RS21750 SAMPLE-300     1     cat1
3 BJE04_RS21780 SAMPLE-300     1     cat1
4 BJE04_RS21785 SAMPLE-300     1     cat2
5 BJE04_RS21790 SAMPLE-300     1     cat2
6          cheA SAMPLE-300     1     cat3
```

now the heatmap plot

```
dfx %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x=gene, y=sample, fill = category, alpha = value)) + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009999","blue", "red", "orange")  ) + 
    geom_tile(colour = "white") + 
    scale_alpha_identity(guide = "none") +
    scale_y_discrete(position = "right") +
    theme_bw() + 
    theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman"), # corresponde a todo en Time New Romans 
          legend.position="non",
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          # font size genes 
          axis.text.x =  element_text(angle = 85, hjust = 1, vjust = 1.05,  size = 9.1, family="Times New Roman" ), 
          axis.title.x = element_blank(),
          # font size samples strains genomes 
          axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1, size = 12.3, family="Times New Roman", face = "bold"),
          axis.title.y = element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank() # remove the numbers in x
    )
```

I just want  to add the annotations using the column category (cat1, cat2, cat3, cat4), like:

[image]

any suggestion ?

thanks

Comment: Would this approach suit? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75669019/12957340